# Matlab OOP: What happens exactly when a get function is called on a property that is an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, instance-variables

I experienced serious performance issues with the get-access of single values of (dependent) properties that are arrays. It seems that when getting a value, the complete array of the property is returned and somewhat indexed *later*.

**What happens exactly when a get function is called on a property that is an array?**

Code Example:

```
% class definition
classdef ArrayProp
    properties
        array
    end
    methods
        function obj = ArrayProp(input)
            obj.array = input;
        end
        function output = get.array(obj)
            output = obj.array
            numel(obj.array)
            numel(output)  
        end
    end 
end

% test script
array         = rand(2,1);
myArray       = ArrayProp(array);
returnedValue = myArray.array(1)

% command window result
output =
0.6180
0.7304
ans =
 2
ans =
 2
returnedValue =
 0.6180
```

Please observe that the number of elements of the output is `2`, but only `1` value is returned to the variable. This experiment is performed with Matlab2011b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations are correct.

Basically, what happens internally (MATLAB being closed source this is obviously only a more or less educated guess) is something like the following:

Your code:

```
returnedValue = myArray.array(1)
```

Internal:

```
intermediate = myArray.array; # this invokes get.array(myArray)
returnedValue = intermediate(1);
```

If you think about it - it's the only reasonable way to do this.
Any other way requires that the `get.array(obj)` method would have to know what's going to happen to the result value - which would make a "universal" implementation much more complicated.

Comment: Okay, thank's! So an alternative way to access a single value would be to pass the index, e.g. `function out=getArray(obj,ind); out=obj.array(ind); end`. Or to overload subsref...

Comment: Correct. I'd go for the first version - implementing subsref can be a real pain.